# List the names of the course(s) student Altvater took in semester I-2008

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im stuck on a question "List the names of the course(s) student Altvater took in semester I-2008" If anyone can guide me to the right direction I would appreciate it. I assume i would use some sort of join. Please refer to this diagram http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/Past/databasefa13/notes/ch07-inclassex.pdf
I understand that I will below parts in my query 
Where StudentName = 'Altvater' and
Where Semester = ‘I-2008’

Comment: What have you tried ? I can see 5 questions, on which question you are facing an issue?

Comment: @hemalp108 The question im stuck is "List the names of the course(s) student Altvater took in semester I-2008"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names are consistent throughout the schema, allowing natural joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CourseName
  FROM STUDENT
       NATURAL JOIN REGISTRATION
       NATURAL JOIN SECTION
       NATURAL JOIN COURSE
 WHERE StudentName = 'Altvater'
       AND Semester = 'I-2008';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following SQL:

```
SELECT COURSENAME
FROM STUDENT S
INNER JOIN REGISTRATION R
ON S.STUDENTID=R.STUDENTID
INNER JOIN SECTION SE
ON R.SECTOINNO=SE.SECTOINNO
AND R.SEMESTER=SE.SEMESTER
INNER JOIN COURSE C
ON SE.COURSEID=C.COURSEID
WHERE S.STUDENTID=54907/* Altvater */
AND R.SEMESTER='I-2008'
```

You just need to understand basic design of tables to write SQL. SQL is very easy language. Let me know if you have any doubt in this query.